# Angular Bind doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a table directive, but when I try to set some binds to my template it isn't working.

This is my $scope.grid object.

```
$scope.grid = {
    title: "My Title",
    isCheckable: true,
    toolbar: [{ text: "", icon: "", hint: "", action: "" }],
    dataSource: "ok",
    dataBind: [{ text: "", bind: "", type: "" }],
    defaultFilter: [{ bind: "" }],
    actions: [{ text: "", icon: "", hint: "", action: "" }]
};
```

If I try

```
$scope.title = $scope.grid.title;
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

It work and show me the title "My Title"

But if I try

```
<div>{{grid.title}}</div>
```

It doesn't work.

*** SOLUTION ***

Delete and recreate the Virtual Directory.
For some reason, it was locking my template with the old version, so, in my template it was showing on html "{{title}}" instead of "{{grid.title}}"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a ng-app and a ng-controller, look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">                </script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

{{grid.title}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.grid = {
    title: "My Title",
    isCheckable: true,
    toolbar: [{ text: "", icon: "", hint: "", action: "" }],
    dataSource: "ok",
    dataBind: [{ text: "", bind: "", type: "" }],
    defaultFilter: [{ bind: "" }],
    actions: [{ text: "", icon: "", hint: "", action: "" }]
};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ng-app and ng-controller is correctly configured.

Like I said, if I try "{{title}}" it shows, but {{grid.title}} doesn't show.

Comment: @LucasFreitas did you checked in your console log to see any errors when you try {{grid.title}} ?

Comment: Yep @Han Arantes, without errors.

Tried to debug too, the $scope.grid correctly have all atributes.

If I try "console.log($scope.grid.title)" it shows on the log, but doesn't appears when I try to bind it.